# Ajax timezone service

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I need to create a web server that, for a time zone other than `X`, sends the current date and time to the web browser (for each incoming request)

URL of the service: `http://localhost:8080/time/`

Can someone explain how should I exactly do that?

Comment: Please describe in details what you want, what you have tried, what has been wrong, etc.

Comment: first, define what `X` is, because that's too vague to ask here. Then describe what YOU mean by "current date and time" i.e. is it the servers timezone or the clients timezone. Then, describe what server side language you will be using, because it's not clear since you've made no attempt to do this yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple REST service in Node.js using [Moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/) and [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) to give a list of timezones and the current time for a timezone when requested.

You'll need to run

```
npm install express moment moment-timezone
```

to install the required packages.

Start the service using node index.js, then point your browser to http://localhost:8080/.

You should see a dropdown of timezones.

Selecting a timezone will display the current time in that timezone.

You can also test the service with curl:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/time -X POST -d "{\"timezone\":\"US/Pacific\"}" -H "content-type: application/json"
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const port = 8080;
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const moment = require("moment");
const momentTimezone = require("moment-timezone");

app.use(express.static("./public"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/timezones', async (req, res) => {
    res.json(moment.tz.names());
})

app.post('/time', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log("/time:", req.body.timezone)
        const timezone = req.body.timezone;
        res.json({ currentTime: moment().tz(timezone).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss") });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});

app.listen(port);
console.log(`Serving at http://localhost:${port}`);
```

Then create a /public directory and create

**/public/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
<body style="margin:50px">
  <h2>Select a timezone</h2>
  <select id="timezone-dropdown" name="timezone">
  </select>
  <p id="output">Output</p>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**/public/app.js**

```
const dropdown = document.getElementById('timezone-dropdown');
const getTimeInterval = 1000; // 1000 milliseconds.
const selectedTimezone = "America/Los_Angeles";

async function getTimezoneList() {
    let response = await fetch('/timezones'); 
    let timezoneList = await response.json();
    timezoneList.forEach(timezone => {
        let option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = timezone;
        option.value = timezone;
        dropdown.add(option);
    });

    // Set the selected timezone
    dropdown.selectedIndex = timezoneList.findIndex(timezone => timezone === selectedTimezone);
}

async function getTimezoneTime(timezone) {
    let response = await fetch("/time", {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({ timezone })
    });
    let timeDetails = await response.json();
    console.log("getTimezoneTime: response: ", timeDetails);
    return timeDetails.currentTime;
}

async function getCurrentTimeForSelectedTimezone() {
    console.log("Getting time for " + dropdown.value);
    const time = await getTimezoneTime(dropdown.value);
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = `<b>Current time: ${time}</b>`
}

getTimezoneList();

// Read the current time every second.
setInterval(getCurrentTimeForSelectedTimezone, getTimeInterval);
```